# The facebook-ion-auth library in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I m new to codeigniter . I m developping a project in which I have used the ion_auth library. I have to make my authentification supports facebook login. I have found facebook-ion-auth , but didn't understand how can I use it. Even in the readme file ,I haven’t found steps of installation. someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Read a tutorial on 
http://www.digitalwhores.net/codeigniter/codeigniter-ion-auth-and-facebook-ion-auth-tutorial/ that I  made a few months ago